# SSRS Pass Arabic in Report Builder Query Parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to figure out how my query in report builder can work with source data column nvarchar and arabic text present. If I try to preview the report it says `@provider parameter requires a value but it doesn't have one`. The data in this column is all arabic. If I test in report build and provider value like `منطقة الرياض` no results are shown.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[CQM_Clinician]
WHERE  @Provider IN ('',[Provider Name])
```

Comment: Make sure the parameter name in SSRS and the SQL variable are spelled the same, SSRS is case sensitive in this instance. Secondly, it's not clear from your question how `@Provider` gets populated, please clarify (manually typed in, select from a list  that comes from a query etc...  - what datatype is the field in the query that supplies data to the parameter etc, etc.

Comment: The source table has a column named [Provider Name] nvarchar(100) which contains data in arabic. the query that is used to generate the dataset is above where @Provider is set as a parameter. I will check if there a case issue.

Comment: The spelling is the same in both SSRS and SQL

Comment: I would use SQL Profiler next to look at exactly what query is being passed to the server. That might help you determine what the problem is. I setup a test case (on my non Arabic supported server) and even on that the query worked, it just returned unreadable characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all who replied to the direction. The issue was i had to pass the parameter with the same datatype. N'Provider_Name'

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CQM_Clinician] WHERE @Provider IN (N'',[Provider Name])